# Rails: query doesn't order with special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to query elements with order by name.

If I simply write Element.all.order('name') then I receive:
aaa
bbb
_ccc
ddd

But I want:
_ccc
aaa
bbb
ddd

I want this because I think adding "_,-,=" is the simplest way to make visual order on the page.

Is it possible to achieve this in query?
Or should I just use ruby 'sort' method?

Thank you!

In console I can do this:
['aaa', 'bbb', '_ccc'].sort
=> ["_ccc", "aaa", "bbb"]

Comment: Well, _ comes after the whole alphabet (you can check with "z" < "_" which returns false). You could use numbers, then idk, use regexp to replace the digit with the underscore (that's the easy fool's solution~).

Comment: But why in console I have this:
['aaa', 'bbb', '_ccc'].sort
=> ["_ccc", "aaa", "bbb"]

Comment: Could be a C thing, or it could programmaticlly prioritise a range of characters to come before letters (& numbers maybe). Could be something completely different, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that order on the Element.all.order() is generating SQL Order By, while ruby sort is a different algorithm, and can be customized in your model code.  Modifying how your database sorts is going to be specific to that database, and may be a configuration option related to your character set.

Comment: Ok, I think I will just use ruby sort. Thank you!